# Alter block form

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm using the contrib module [contact block](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_block) and I would like to edit the block form settings. By default, there is a textfield (title) and the "Display title" checkbox, I need to hide those fields by use of some hook(s) but I don't know which one should I use, already tested:

- hook_form_alter()
- hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()

My form.
[image]

How could I hide them (without css)? Thanks all.

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried when testing `hook_form_alter`?

Comment: I just debugged the generic form alter to see if it came in

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hook_form_alter` do this but first should check the form concern only your block, if you check only on `$form_id == 'block_form'` you will hide those field in all block forms.
Try with the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MyModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if the provider is contact_block, to target only contact_block form
  if ($form_id == 'block_form' && isset($form['settings']['provider']['#value']) && $form['settings']['provider']['#value'] == 'contact_block') {
    // Hide  Display title checkbox
    $form['settings']['label_display']['#access'] = FALSE;
    // Hide title textfield
    $form['settings']['label']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
```